# INFOPATH message 'The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

Hi,

I have a submit button on my InfoPath form with some rules.

Its been working fine since last 4 years, but since last 1 week one of my user , when he clicks on submit button he gets below message

"'The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?"

but when the form gets closed nothing saves , none of the changes gets saved.

However, it is working fine for me.

The only difference being I am having "Sitecollection admin" access and he has "contribute" access.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the InfoPath form you should get a message saying something has changed do you want to update. Click yes and then save and publish. This should fix your problem.

The cause is because you have changed something in the design of the underlying list. Maybe added a field, changed its name, altered some choices, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message “'The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?” will be received by user adding or editing an item but deciding to click the close button to cancel the creation/modification of the item.

This user is trying to close the form without saving.

What are the rules configured on the submit button in the form?

If you create a Submit button, does it work?

[image]